# Windows 7 not showing in OS selection menu at start up

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, windows-7

I have 4 partitions (`C:`, `D:`, `E:` & `F:`) on my 500GB HHD.
I have two OS installed on my PC, Windows XP on drive `C:` and Windows 7 on drive `D:`.

Today I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.10 on drive `C:` and install all the necessary drivers but when I restart my computer there was no option in the OS selection menu to boot Windows 7.

I want to boot Windows 7 as soon as possible, how can I do this?

Comment: Boot on Ubuntu and execute in a terminal `sudo update-grub2`. Reboot and see if the entry was added.

Comment: BTW Ubuntu 11.10 support has ended some days ago. Unless you have a specific reason to use it you should try a newer version.

Comment: Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-12-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-12-generic
done

Comment: Can you provide the output of `sudo fdisk -l`? (Use paste.ubuntu.com or something similar)

Comment: Here is it http://paste.ubuntu.com/5713785/

Comment: A report generated by 'Boot Repair' http://paste.ubuntu.com/5713808/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As GRUB can't detect your Windows system, the best way to solve this is to create a manual entry to Windows.

Edit `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` (you will need root permission) and add the following at the end:

```
menuentry "Windows 7" {
    insmod part_msdos
    set root="(hd0,msdosN)"
    chainloader +1
}
```

you will have to replace "N" with the correct windows partition where you have Windows 7 (if you don't know which one it is you can use `gparted` or if it is available, "Disc Utility"). So if your Windows partition is `/dev/sda3` the correct text would be

```
set root="(hd0,msdos3)"
```

After that just run `sudo update-grub2` and you should have a new entry once you reboot.

Comment: @4mir From your Boot Repair log, it seems that the Windows partition is `/dev/sda4`